# Bluetooth LE advertising

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to Advertise a timestamp. The following code works fine on some devices but fails on others with error 1, which is "ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE".

I have already included setIncludeDeviceName(false) on my builder object in order to save some bytes for packing my own, as suggested elsewhere. However the problem persists. Here is my code:

```
private static final String OUR_SERVICE_UUID = "a1b35dbc-f701-4df4-831b-74c2ecedf12c";

ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(OUR_SERVICE_UUID));

long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .addServiceData(pUuid,ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt((int) timeNow).array())
            .build();
```

Comment: Strange thing! Can you name some not working devices? Do the not working devices already perform some ble advertising?

Comment: It works on: Samsung A310, Moto E4, Huawei SCL-L01,LG V20

Comment: It doesnt work on: Pixel 2